# How to send input in the debug mode of IDEA IntelliJ?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, stdin, jetbrains-ide

In IntelliJ IDEA, I couldn't send input while the debug mode reaches the line

```
String i = in.nextLine();
```

which is waiting for user input.

==============================================

The screenshot is as follows.

[image: couldn't do anything while program block in waiting for stdin]

Comment: Open the console window to give input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your console is hidden in debug mode. See the right most icon with `>` symbol right next to profiler. click on it and it must  open the console.

[image]

Another way is `right click on Debugger and choose Layout and check mark Console`.

[image]